# Is there any way to use useEffect for both empty array and [props and states] values in same jsx file?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am implementing a search bar filter kind of module for my ecommerce project. I need to fetch data from api call when the page starts loading which I can manage by use-Effect hooks. But there is a text field present for searching, for category, product name etc. that state value keep changing while typing in search bar. That's why I need to use-Effect for states also.. But How can I make both things work on same file?

`

```
useEffect(() => {
    applyFilters();
}, [selectedRating, categories, searchInput]);
```

`

```
 useEffect(() => {
        /*fetch products from api call */
    
}, []);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple `useEffect`s in the same component is [allowed by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns).

```js
/* For state change of internal components */
useEffect(() => {
    applyFilters();
}, [selectedRating, categories, searchInput]);


/* For API fetch call */
 useEffect(() => {
        /*fetch products from api call */
}, []);
```